# The use of "as"

Tags: grammar, meaning

> "Such an assumption puts us in the way of a non-arbitrary, full,
> detailed, coherent causal account of that experience to an extent
> which no alternative story comes anywhere near rivalling. It can
> therefore be judged rational to accept it by the same criteria of
> rationality as govern our assessment of explanatory theories framed in
> natural scientific enquiry or empirical inquiries generally. I shall
> return to this answer later."

[P. F. Strawson, Scepticism and Naturalism: Some Varieties]

I don't understand how to use the word "as" in the passage. Does it have to be combined with the word "same" to become "the same ... as"?

Comment: Yes - it's only the word ***same*** that licenses ***as*** in this context. Without ***same***, it would have to be ***...that** govern our assessment...* (which so far as I'm concerned would also be fine as *the **same** criteria **that** govern...* anyway).